# How can I get the chat history of a group in Telegram?

Tags: javascript, typescript, telegram, telegram-bot

I would like to get the chat history (all messages) that were posted in a public group on Telegram. How can I do this with JavaScript/TypeScript?

I've found this method in the API https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory which I think looks like what I'm trying to do. But how do I actually call it?

I use node-telegram-bot-api.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

You can't do this via node-telegram-bot-api library (or any Telegram Bot library).

**Long answer**:

This API you mentioned (https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory) is Telegram API.
But you are using node-telegram-bot-api - this is Telegram Bot API (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) which are not the same things.

***Telegram API*** - this API is for creating user applications (like a telegram client).
***Telegram Bot API*** - this API is for creating bots in telegram.

So, you can't get the chat history using Telegram Bot API (which used in he lib node-telegram-bot-api). Bots don't have permission for this.

But you can use Telegram API to do this, but in this case you need to create "user bot" (you need a real telegram user for this, to login into account, join to the group and receive messages from grop (in case group permissions allows this)).